# How do I suppress headers on a multi-record Crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on a report of invoices that can be run for one invoice or mulitple records.

On the first page of each record there should be header information, but on the second page of the record it should be suppressed.

Some invoices are one page, but some are two, some are three; it varies.

The Grouping does not seem to be working, it is putting large spaces on the invoices and I am looking for a formula that resets every time the record changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Group on invoice and move the column headers to the Group Header.
2. In the group header section, ***Suppress*** property, enter the following expression:

   **InRepeatedGroupHeader;**